# Finding the limit of $\lim_{v\to180}\frac{360\cos\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)}{180-v}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, pi

I need to find this limit:

$\displaystyle\lim_{v\to180}\frac{360\cos\left(\dfrac{v}{2}\right)}{180-v}$, with $v$ in degrees.

I have tried to do this:

$\displaystyle\lim_{v\to180}\frac{360\cos\left(\dfrac{v}{2}\right)}{180-v}=^{L'H}\displaystyle\lim_{v\to180}\frac{-\frac{360}{2}\sin\left(\dfrac{v}{2}\right)}{-1}=180\sin\left(\dfrac{v}{2}\right)=180$.

This is wrong though, because its limit is actually $\pi$. I realise that $\pi$ radians = 180 degrees, but as far as i can tell nothing is linking degrees and radians in the formula. Could someone show me how to find this limit?

Comment: And now you've found that differential/integral calculus just does **not** work "as supposed" when instead radians we use degrees...! In fact, if you're going to work with degrees, you will **have to** use the equivalence $$180\;deg. =\pi\;rad.$$otherwise, for example, $\;\cos\frac{180}2=\cos90\neq 0\;$ since $\;\cos 90\;radians\neq 0\;$ ...!

Comment: @DonAntonio Ah thank you! Is this because I can't take the derivative of a trig function if it is in degrees, hence L'Hôpital's rule doesn't work?

Comment: Yes...or, in fact, because $\;\cos(x\;rad.)=\cos\frac{180x}{\pi}\;deg.\;$. Now use the chain rule....but, of course, it is too cumbersome.

Comment: The best way to think of it is as follows: the functions $\sin$, $\cos$, $\tan$, etc. are functions that take *numbers* and give *numbers*. Those numbers they take can be seen as representing angle measure in radians only. If you want to deal with degrees, you always need a conversion factor: $\cos x^\circ = \cos \left(\frac \pi {180} x\right)$. To put a finer point on it, $\cos 90$ simply does not ever mean the cosine of a right angle (except perhaps in a sloppy geometry class). It's the cosine of a $90$-*radian* angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translate to radians in order to make sense of the usual differential stuff we know:

$$\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{2\pi\cos\frac x2}{\pi -x}\stackrel{\text{l'Hôpital}}=\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{-\pi\sin\frac x2}{-1}=\pi$$

Comment: Thank you. Would we have a way to do this if we didn't know about radians? By the way you might want to change l'Hospital to l'Hopital.

Comment: Both forms, with and without "s", are correct...and without knowing about radians we couldn't possibly do sense with the differentials...

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know that, but now I do :). What about ways of doing it without differentials?

Answer (score 1):

$$cos(\frac{v}{2})=sin\frac{1}{2}(180-v)$$let $t=180-v$ then limit changes to $$\lim_{t\to0} \frac{360sin(\frac{t}{2})}{t}$$multiply and divide by $2$ to get the limit as $180$